# Sitefinity - Validating Custom Form Field

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity, sitefinity-4, sitefinity-5

I have a class `MyField` that extends `FormField` (it is a custom Form Field I can add via Form Builder). I have one field in the `.ascx` file:

```
<telerik:TextField ID="Status" CssClass="sfTxtID" style="visibility:hidden;" runat="server">
</telerik:TextField>
```

Currently, if the user presses the `Submit` button the form submits even though the `Status` TextField is empty.

My question is: How can I validate my field when the submit button is pressed and show an error if its not filled out?

Comment: Is this in the frontend or the backend?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have a problem with the Forms control in that it doesn't allow Radio Button Lists to be validated (especially when you select the option to not select any options by default)

Comment: I didn't get an answer yet but I will hopefully get one soon. I'll answer the question if I get the answer.

Comment: This is going to sound really silly, but have you tried just a general validator controls? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hidden controls do not get checked by validation. [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_properties)

Comment: A bit more explanation of the problem and the reason you say it is not going to be checked by validation would be helpful instead of just a reference to the link.